# What is a good open source package for building flexible spam detection on a large Rails site?

Tags: ruby, linux, soa, spam, bayesian

My site is getting larger and it's starting to attract a lot of spam through various channels.  The site has a lot of different types of UGC (profiles, forums, blog comments, status updates, private messages, etc, etc).  I have various mitigation efforts underway, which I hope to deploy in a blitzkrieg fashion to convince the spammers that we're not a worthwhile target.  I have high confidence in what I'm doing functionality wise, but one missing piece is killing all the old spam all at once.

Here's what I have:

- **Large good/bad corpora** (5-figure bad, 6 or 7-figure good).  A lot of the spam has very reliable fingerprints, and the fact that I've sort of been ignoring it for 6 months helps :)
- **Large, modular Rails site deployed to AWS**.  It's not a huge traffic site, but we're running 8 instances with the beginnings of a SOA.
- **Ruby, Redis, Resque, MySQL, Varnish, Nginx, Unicorn, Chef, all on Gentoo**

My requirements:

1. I want it to perform reasonably well given the volume of data (therefore I'm wary of a pure ruby solution).
2. I should be able to train multiple classifications to different types of content (419-scam vs botnet link spam)
3. I would like to be able to add manual factors based on our own detective work (pattern matching, IP reuse, etc)
4. Ultimately I want to construct a nice interface to be used with Ruby.  If this requires getting my hands dirty in C or whatever, I can handle it, but I'll avoid it if I can.

I realize this is a long and vague question, but what I'm looking for primarily is just a list of good packages, and secondarily any random thoughts from someone who has built a similiar system about ways to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We looked for an acceptable open source solution and didn't find one.

If you come to the same conclusion and decide to consider proprietary anti-spam, check out the paid [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) collaborative spam filtering service. We've had decent performance from it across a dozen medium sized sites. It integrates with rails through rack and [rackismet](https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet).

Comment: Definitely one thing I considered.  I question the performance and relative cost of it, especially considering the different corpora I want to train for different purposes.  Maybe I'm misguided, but I'm gonna keep looking to roll my own for the moment...